# Codeigniter doesn't return some records which are present in database

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter, select, where-clause

I am having a strange error. 
I have users table in database. 
where I am executing a query through module function as below.

```
function getUserInfo($id)
 {      
    $query = $this->db->from('user')
                  ->where('id', $id)
                  ->get();
    return $query->result();        
}
```

This function doesn't return me some users which are present in database. `$id` is present.
I can get them if I execute same query in mysql workbench. 
This is happening only for some users which I created through application. 
This function returns data for other users which I imported directly while creating table. 
This is complete strange problem. There is no error message. It just work for some users not for others. There is no problem on database connectivity also. Could you please suggest if there any reason behind this? 
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Are there any differences at all in the records besides some were created in app and some imported? When it doesn't retrieve records, are there any errors in the PHP log file, or MySQL log file?

Comment: No... All records are correct. There is no error in php or mysql log file. it just return empty result

Comment: If you take your where clause out, does it show all records?  Just trying to narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: Yes. When I put no condition, it returns all records & also when there are id from imported data, it returns result. It only doesn't work for new users that I created through application. Its makes no sense to me. I am scratching my head since last few hours & couldn't find any reason or logic behind this problem. DOes it have anything related to how database is created ?

Comment: if this helps, when I imported data, id which is primary key is inserted through import query, but when I create user from application, id is auto incremented. is there something behind this?

Comment: Sorry...That is a strange problem...Not sure I have ever seen that before. It sounds like the id field is the problem, but without being able to look at your DB, it would be hard to know.  Have you tried querying based on another field (name or something for example) to see if you can pull from the problem records at all?

Comment: If you hardcode one of the IDs in your table and try, are you getting any results ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found answer. sometimes most of strange error have silly mistake behind it. I didn't check current database connection, As I was working on parrallel databases when I execute, it switch to other db somehow. I fixed it now. Sorry couldn't imagine this could have been one of reason behind the problem. THank for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getUserInfo($id)
 {      
    $query = $this->db->where('id', $id)
                      ->get('user');

    echo "empty results ! query was :".$this->db->last_query()."<br/>\n";

    return $query->result();        
}
```

add this line and check the query. there must be something wrong with the `$id` you pass to user or something that is causing a silent error.

let me know what you get from `last_query();`